# Rails 5: How can I get Google Analytics to work?

Tags: heroku, google-analytics, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks, railsapps

I tried to install google analytics on a **Rails 5** website adding the Google Analytics Tracking Script created by Jonathon Wolfe and provided on Nick Reed’s **Turbolinks Compatibility** site.

- I replaced UA-XXXXXXX-XX with my Google Analytics tracking ID
- the file app/assets/javascripts/application.js has the //= require_tree . directive
- I deployed to heroku as described in [Analytics for Rails](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-google-analytics.html)
- I **did not include** the rails_12factor gem as in https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor says.

Google Analytics still don't get tracking data from my website. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I use slim templating, so make changes according to your templating engine.
In `application.html.slim` in head initialize ga

```
javascript:
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-XX', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

in `ga.js.coffee`

```
document.addEventListener 'turbolinks:load', (event) ->
  if typeof ga is 'function'
    ga('set', 'location', event.data.url)
    ga('send', 'pageview')
```

Bonus. I also use infinite scroll, so when I load data in index.js.erb
I use this to send another page view to ga

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
... rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used this page http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/google_analytics.html with the set up you posted above you need to change your `application.js` to `application.js.coffee`. All of that code is written in coffeescript.